# How to use PhpStorm to autocomlete style sheets

Tags: editor, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using PhpStorm for a Bootstrap project.

Is there any way to make PhpStorm autocomplete get and predict CSS classes from external file without linking this file to the edited file?

Or any way to select stylesheet file and make PhpStorm use its' classes inside whole project without linking this CSS file to the edited file?

Comment: Give some details. I, for example, use Twig/Blade templates .. and PhpStorm is unaware that I have linked any CSS there (it's linked, but via special tags so that IDE treats them as plain strings) ... but I still have code completion for all Bootstrap classes. Obviously, I do have Bootstrap .css files somewhere in my project -- they are not clicked from CDN or some another external link.

Comment: i am using laravel with vue project... the bootstrap css file is inserted inside the laravel public files and vue html .vue files is used in another directory in the project  ... so is there any way to inject the bootstrap css file manually to be supported in all project .vue html as classes files

Comment: I'm not using VueJS or .vue files so cannot give you precise answer. But where are your Bootstrap files are located and what are they? (.css files inside a `public` folder .. or they are inside `node_modules` etc . .or maybe linked from CDN directly)?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML templates/partials completion includes selectors from all project stylesheets - unless you have some styles explicitly linked/embedded in your partial via `<link>` or `<style>` tag. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2223 and linked tickets.
Vuejs templates will be treated differently since 2017.2 - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25767